# Implicit differentiation problem contradiction?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I have been doing a few exercises involving implicit differentiation, and I encountered a contradiction(or that is at least what I think it is):

[image]

So here, in the beginning $\frac d {du}$ is done on both sides of equation.

However, in the book it says like this:

[image]

And an example from the book:
[image]

So if I **apply the logic from the book** in my above problem the solution would say: The system of equations given in this problem corresponds to: $(\frac {du} {dx})_y$, and to calculate it we regard $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x$ and $y$ and differentiate the given equations with respect to x, holding y constant. Hence I would not differentiate this with $\frac d {du}$ like they did, but with $\frac d {dx}$. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything.

You will get the same result anyway.

$ u= x^2+y$ therefore $1= (2x)x_u +y_u$ and $ v= x+y^2$ therefore $0 = x_u +(2y)y_u$

Comment: This is the way the problem is solved in the solutions. But my question is: If I apply the logic from the book that I stated above, I would have to differentiate this with $\frac d {dx}$ and not $\frac d {du}$ as in the solutions?

Comment: $\frac d {dx}(x^2+y)=(2x)$ and you multiply by $x_u$ which gives you the same result.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why do you multiply it by $x_u$, that is, why do we differentiate with respect to $u$, and not with respect to $x$?

Comment: we are applying implicit differentiation assuming  that $x$ is a function of $u$